# Python Unit Testing Google Bigquery

Tags: python, unit-testing, google-bigquery

I am having trouble in unit testing the following code block:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.oauth2 import service_account

def run_query(query, gcp_ser_acc):
    credentials = 
    service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(gcp_ser_acc)
    client = bigquery.Client(gcp_ser_acc['project_id'], credentials)
    query_job = client.query(query)
    results = query_job.result()
    return results
```

I am new to mocking and I have tried the following test:

```
def test_run_a_query_with_real_key(self):
    gcp_ser_acc = {
                'project_id': 'my_project_id',
                'private_key': 'my_private_key',
                'token_uri': 'my_token_uri',
                'client_email': 'my_client_email'
                }
    with mock.patch('service_account.Credentials', call_args=gcp_ser_acc, return_value={}):
        with mock.patch('bigquery.Client', call_args=(gcp_ser_acc['project_id'], {}), return_value={}):
            run_query('SELECT 1+1 as col', gcp_ser_acc)
            assert service_account.Credentials.called
            assert bigquery.Client.called
```

Can anybody mock the google stuff and write a unit test please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is how you mock google.cloud.bigquery with pytest, pytest-mock

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery


schema = [
    bigquery.SchemaField("full_name", "STRING", mode="REQUIRED"),
    bigquery.SchemaField("age", "INTEGER", mode="REQUIRED"),
]


def some_query(table_name='blahblahbloo'):

    client = bigquery.Client()
    table_id = f"project.dataset.{table_name}"
    table = bigquery.Table(table_id, schema=schema)
    table = client.create_table(table)


def test_some_query(mocker):
    mock_table = mocker.patch('google.cloud.bigquery.Table', autospec=True)
    mock_client = mocker.patch('google.cloud.bigquery.Client', autospec=True)

    some_query()  # run with mocked objects

    mock_table.assert_called_with('project.dataset.blahblahbloo', schema=schema)
    mock_client().create_table.assert_called_with(mock_table.return_value)
```

Comment: Did you have a chance to run. Just wondering if it does work.

Comment: Yup, feel free to try it

Comment: Can you help with this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77241495/how-to-mock-google-bigquery-client-for-unittests-in-pytests

Answer (score 2):

While it might be possible to improve the mocks here, it isn't going to provide much value to you as a test.  In your code, there's two basic things you can be testing:

1. Are you passing in correct credentials etc to use BigQuery correctly.
2. Is your application's business logic around the query and result processing correct.

For (1), no unit test is going to provide you actual reassurance that your code works on GCP. All it will do is show that it does the thing that your tests check for. Instead of unit testing, consider some kind of integration or system test that actual makes a for-real call to GCP (but don't run this as often as unit tests)

Unit tests are a good fit for (2), however your function as it currently stands doesn't really do anything.  If you did - lets say some code that instantiates an object for each result row - then we could unit test that.

Comment: As a new bee in python unit testing, I need a better way of mocking all those bigquery functions so that I don't need to use actual bigquery to run a query. I strongly believe we can mock those functions and test the behaviour accordingly.