# Test FastAPI with Big Query client in backend

Tags: python, testing, mocking, pytest, fastapi

I'm writing a REST API in FastAPI where I have to use Big Query for fetching data. I have problems with creating unit tests for positive scenarios where everything goes fine. I'm a beginner in API unit testing and I don't know how to mock Big Query Client.

Below please find the simplified code showing the overall idea of what I want to achieve. Ask me if you need more details and I will edit the post.

`main.py`

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends

app = FastAPI()


def get_bq_client():
    with bigquery.Client() as client:
        return client


def prepare_query(val1):
    query = f"""
         SELECT name, item_id, price
         FROM `bigquery-my-data.products`
         WHERE item_id = {val1}
     """

    return query


@app.get("/v1/items/{item_id}")
async def get_price(item_id: int,
                    bq_client: bigquery.client.Client = Depends(get_bq_client)
                    ):
    query = prepare_query(item_id)

    bq_client = bigquery.Client()
    query_job = bq_client.query(query)
    result = query_job.query().to_dataframe()

    return result.to_json()
```

`test_main.py`

```
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from main import app

client = TestClient(app)


def test_get_price_correct():
    response = client.get("/v1/items/123")
    expected = {"name": "Cola",
                "item_id": 123,
                "price": 1.12}
    pass
```

I've found this thread but I failed to adapt it for mocking the client response: [Python Unit Testing Google Bigquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53700181/python-unit-testing-google-bigquery).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking through the FastAPI testing documentation, this can be achieved using the [`dependency_overrides`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/testing-dependencies/) functionality.

```
# main.py

from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI
from google.cloud import bigquery

app = FastAPI()


def get_bq_client():
    with bigquery.Client() as client:
        return client


def prepare_query(val1):
    query = f"""
         SELECT name, item_id, price
         FROM `bigquery-my-data.products`
         WHERE item_id = {val1}
     """

    return query


@app.get("/v1/items/{item_id}")
async def get_price(
    item_id: int, bq_client: bigquery.client.Client = Depends(get_bq_client)
):
    query = prepare_query(item_id)
    query_job = bq_client.query(query)
    result = query_job.query().to_dataframe()

    return result.to_json()

# test_main.py

import re
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

from fastapi.testclient import TestClient

from main import app, get_bq_client

client = TestClient(app)


def test_get_price_correct():
    PATTERN = re.compile(r"(?:item_id = )(\d+)")
    expected = {"name": "Cola", "item_id": 123, "price": 1.12}
    # remove the item id so we can dynamically get it from the query
    cloned = expected.copy()
    cloned["item_id"] = None

    mock_bq_client = MagicMock()
    mock_bq_client.configure_mock(
        **{
            "query.return_value.query.return_value.to_dataframe.return_value.to_json.return_value": cloned
        }
    )

    def mock_get_bq_client():
        return mock_bq_client

    # override dependency to return a mock object
    app.dependency_overrides[get_bq_client] = mock_get_bq_client
    response = client.get("/v1/items/123")
    # grab the query, strip whitespace and newlines
    query = mock_bq_client.query.call_args.args[0].strip("\n").strip()
    # grab the item id
    item_id = PATTERN.search(query).group(1)
    blob = response.json()
    blob.update({"item_id": int(item_id)})

    assert blob == expected
```

Running it shows the success.

```
================================================================ test session starts ================================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.9.6, pytest-7.2.0, pluggy-1.0.0 -- ****
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: ***, configfile: pytest.ini
plugins: ***
collected 1 item                                                                                                                                    

tests/test_main.py::test_get_price_correct PASSED                                                                                             [100%]

================================================================= 1 passed in 0.19s =================================================================
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please elaborate how does this piece of code work: 
mock_bq_client.configure_mock(
**{          "query.return_value.query.return_value.to_dataframe.return_value.to_json.return_value": cloned
        }
    )

Comment: that specifies how the mock behaves, it follows the chain of calls that are performed on the client so that we can return the item we expect --> https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.configure_mock